# Jmeter- How to read an xml attribute value from the response of a HTTP Sampler

Tags: xml, testing, xpath, jmeter, httpresponse

How can I get the atrribute value from a response of a HTTP sampler and use that variable in other sampler?

Another issue is the HTTP sampler from which I want to get the attribute value have more than one Element with same name, so I have to loop through the entire node and fetch the value of the attribute, how can I achieve this?

Comment: PMD UBIK-INGENIERIEs answer seems to answer your question. If you had something else in mind how you provider about more details. Like sample input/output, jmeter script or your test plan in pseudo code

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have :

```
<toto>
    <titi name="123" />
    <titi name="321" /> 
</toto>
```

And if I understand you want to retrieve the 2 values **123** and **321**

Do the following:

- Add an [XPath_Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) as a child of HTTP Sampler:

  ```
  XPath Query : /toto/titi/@name
  Reference Name : fullAnswer
  ```
- Add a [BeanShell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler):

  ```
  int number = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("fullAnswer_matchNr"));
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  for(int i=0;i<number;i++) {
      builder.append(vars.get("fullAnswer_"+(i+1)));
  }
  vars.put("body", builder.toString());
  ```
- You will obtain as JMeter variables:

  ```
  body=123321
  fullAnswer=123
  fullAnswer_1=123
  fullAnswer_2=321
  fullAnswer_matchNr=2
  ```